# How to run Android Wear signed apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am creating a watch face for android wear. After creating watch face and reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html), I have generated signed apk for android wear.

But android studio is generating two signed apk: one for mobile device and another for wearable.

I want to pack my wearable app inside my mobile app so that watchface appear on companion app as shown on developer's guide.

I installed `mobile-release.apk` but when I open it it doesn't showing in companion app or anywhere. Can anyone help me how to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use android studio:

Your mobile build.gradle file should have the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

Go to Build > Generate signed apk. In the first window, select mobile as your module.

Now when the build is complete, the wear module will automatically be embedded into the mobile module. The mobile apk is the one you distribute. Wear can be used for testing.